# Particular User Unable To Connect To FTP

Tags: networking, server, ftp, vsftpd

I am unable to connect to my FTP server running vsftpd on Ubuntu server 15.04. I have added the user and changed the password, but will still not connect. However, I can connect as the user who setup the server. Below is my config. Thanks for the help.

```
listen=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=whoever
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
sll_enable=YES
```

Comment: Did you check the log file `/var/log/vsftpd.log` for any more clues?

Comment: There is no log file in that location and I have the log enabled too....

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the user itself... I added a new user `useradd -d 'location' 'newuser'` Then chowned the user to the new directory.